# NoClassDefinitionFoundError while packaging using maven

Tags: java, maven, jar

This is my `pom.xml`. When I do `mvn package` and try to execute the jar

```
$ java -jar fft-java-1.0.0.jar
```

I get an error message like the following..

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/jtransforms/fft/DoubleFFT_2D
```

**pom.xml**

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <groupId>com.prasanna</groupId>
  <artifactId>fft-java</artifactId>
  <version>1.0.0</version>
  <packaging>jar</packaging>

  <name>fft-java</name>
  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

  <properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
  </properties>

  <dependencies>
      <dependency>
          <groupId>com.github.wendykierp</groupId>
          <artifactId>JTransforms</artifactId>
          <version>3.0</version>
      </dependency>
  </dependencies>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <!-- Build an executable JAR -->
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.4</version>
                <configuration>
                    <archive>
                        <manifest>
                            <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
                            <classpathPrefix>lib/</classpathPrefix>
                            <mainClass>com.prasanna.TestFFT</mainClass>
                        </manifest>
                    </archive>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

But I am actually able to see the class DoubleFFT_2D in the package org.jtransforms.fft
How would I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Check your manifest if it has the import for it. or try mvm clean install on the project first and then try mvm clean package.

Comment: mvn clean install package did not solve the issue. I am new to maven. Manifest should be handled by maven right?

Comment: Yes but some times it doesn't form it correctly because the import that you have used might be wrong. so delete the manifest and do mvm clean install you should get a new one generated check that.